# Do I have to restart tomcat everything for every jsp or java change?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am running tomcat v7.0 within my eclipse. I have to restart tomcat for every single jsp or java change. I am sure I have set my server wrong somehow. How can I see my changes without keep restarting tomcat?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to deploy and undeploy your application instead. Or [integrate](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

When you are deploying to the tomcat from eclipse, If you are planning to work without deploying every time you to a change to the code base, you can use Jrebel.

Jrebel will sense your changes and take care of the re-deploying. Only issue is that It is a have to buy plugin and I know there are opensource or free applications like that.

Comment: Yes, best commercial hot code replacement tool, even reloads Spring contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the application in DEBUG mode, it will auto restart every time you make any change to ur JSP or java code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the tomcat instance from eclipse and also the Servers folder that is present in the Project Explorer. Add your server to eclipse again and deploy your war file. The changes to JSP or javascript files will now reflect without a server restart.

Answer (score 0):

That not necessary it's depend upon your configuration
When you configure Tomcat in eclipse then we have 3 option

1. never publish automatically
2. automatically publish when resource change
3. automatically publish after build event

so you can configure this as per your requirement.You get this option once you create tomcat server in eclipse ,then select the tomcat server,then either press F3 or right click and open.
i prefer point 2 to select and make sure you have uncheck build automatically in eclipse ,so that once you sure about all the changes you can build the project and tomcat get restart automaticcaly